# How to understand private instance methods in ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript

Per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#private_instance_methods)(emphasis mine):

> ##### Private instance methods
>
> Unlike their public counterparts, private instance methods:
>
> - are installed immediately before the instance fields are installed, and
> - are only available on instances of the class, not on its .prototype property.

I tried to understand 'are installed immediately before the instance fields are installed' and wrote the following code:

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  publicField = 10
  constructor(){
    console.log(this); 
    this.publicField = 20
  }
  #privateMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
}
new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
```

I can see on the console that 'private instance methods' and 'instance fields' have already been installed on 'this'. The concept of not being able to see the execution process is confusing to me, so I wanted to ask this question to make sure: Is '#privateMethod' installed before 'publicField = 10'?

[image]

@Pointy  Is that so?  I really didn't expect that! Thank you very much!

```js
class ClassWithPrivateMethod {
  publicField = this.#privateMethod();
  #privateMethod() {
    return 42;
  }
}
new ClassWithPrivateMethod();
```

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself? Declare an instance property and initialize it with a call to a private instance method.  You'll learn a lot more about the language if you spend a few hours thinking of and trying your own experiments before coming here to ask questions.

Comment: it just means that private methods (i.e. functions) are added to a class instance before instance fields (i.e. variables) are. That's a technical detail that will almost certainly _never_ affect you, but it's important for folks who work on JS parsers/interpreters.